# How do I search titles in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am using LIKE operator for searching the title. But it not giving desired result when the user types word with spaces, what can be done?

Example: title has - national foundation

When I type `national`, it returns this title but when `national geography`, it shows no result found. How to remove this space or how to search properly when user types with spaces?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Off-hand, I would suggest splitting the word by spaces. e.g. "WORD1 WORD2" becomes `LIKE '%WORD1%' OR LIKE '%WORD2%'` (for a very primitive solution).

Comment: @Nishant: Good bid. I got about half-way through and said "I'm just looking to convey this question better, I could spend all day correcting it.". ;p

Comment: V.TITLE LIKE '%".$str."%' OR V.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%".$str."%')

Comment: @Brad Christie sorry, simul-edit. Though I did see the message saying already edited. I type slow.

Comment: @shanmugavel-php Were you able to resolve it with the solution mentioned below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Title FROM table
WHERE MATCH (title)
AGAINST ('national geography');
```

Comment: Kudos for the [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html) recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

assuming the search query the user inputs is stored in `$search`

```
$ex=explode(' ',$search);
$tempq='';
foreach ($ex as $s){
    $tempq.=" or title sounds like '$s' ";
}
$tempq=substr($tempq,4);
$results=mysql_query("select * from TABLE where $tempq");
```

for better and faster results remove the 'sounds' , index your column , limit search queries .

'sound like' will return results that sounds together ex : may return "like" if user searched for "layk" ...
i hope this helps .